# ContentHandler is undefined

Tags: python, xml, sax, saxparser

I'm trying to learn Python's SAX module from O'Reilly's *[Python and XML](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001285)*. I'm trying to run the following sample code, but I keep getting an error and I can't figure out why.

The first file is `handlers.py`:

```
class ArticleHandler(ContentHandler):
    """
    A handler to deal with articles in XML
    """

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        print "Start element:", name
```

The second file is `art.py`, which imports the first file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# art.py

import sys

from xml.sax import make_parser
from handlers import ArticleHandler

ch = ArticleHandler( )

saxparser = make_parser( )
saxparser.setContentHandler(ch)
saxparser.parse(sys.stdin)
```

When I try to run `art.py`, I get the following:

```
% python art.py < article.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "art.py", line 7, in <module>
    from handlers import ArticleHandler
  File "~/handlers.py", line 1, in <module>
    class ArticleHandler(ContentHandler):
NameError: name 'ContentHandler' is not defined
```

I'm probably missing something obvious. Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import ContentHandler in handlers.py as follows:

```
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. (Somehow, I missed this in the book's errata, but here is is: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596001285)